# Transiting in Budapest - one ticket or two?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, transit, airport-transfer, connecting-flights

Foreigners are barred entry in Hungary due to covid.
However, it's not clear whether a foreigner can connect in a Hungarian airport to reach another nation.
So I asked Budapest airport, and was told I am authorized to transfer at their airport without leaving the area.

However, here is where matters get messy: the flight company (Wizz Air) doesn't provide combined tickets, so I would have **two separate tickets**.
According to Wizz Air, this means that I would need to **enter the nation** even only to connect and, as a consequence, they wouldn't allow me to board the flight to Budapest.

In other words, I think, I would be forced to go landside, which I am not allowed.

Potentially relevant details: I would be travelling with cabin baggage only, I have Italian passport, and I plan to travel from Ireland to Italy passing through Budapest (two flights).

Do you know if there is any workaround to that?
Any potentially useful comment welcome.

PS: not sure if I should ask here or on law.stackexchange.

Comment: Unlike many EU states, Hungary did not make an exemption in their travel ban for EU nationals. You would have to clear immigration in Budapest regardless of whether you have separate tickets, because both Hungary and Italy are in the Schengen area. You should not book these tickets.

Comment: Strange. This clashes with what both Wizz Air and Budapest airport told me.

Comment: Michael Hampton and Wizzair are right: on this itinerary, you must enter Hungary, and thus cannot transit airside in Budapest. The BUD > Italy flight is domestic — all within Schengen — and will depart from a different part of the Budapest airport from where you arrive, one with no passport formalities. You cannot access this flight unless you enter Hungary, and get to the BUD terminal for "domestic" flights. The Budapest airport person was wrong, and may not have understood that you were coming from a non-Schengen country (Ireland) and transferring to an inter-Schengen flight.

Comment: Thank you both. And thanks @DavidSupportsMonica for improving the title of the post.

Comment: You're welcome! It's amusing to note that vis-a-vis transiting, it doesn't matter whether you use one ticket or two: you still must pass through Schengen immigration in BUD and enter Hungary to accomplish this itinerary.

Comment: It looked like a (somehow) happy ending. However, I just got this answer from BUD airport which jeopardises everything again, see below. Should I maybe post another question more focused on the architecture of BUD airport? Any feedback welcome.
Note that I clarified to them all the details (itinerary, etc).
 "I got now the confirmation that you can transfer even with 2 valid tickets. (of course if the plane is not cancelled) You do not need to go landside. Kind regards, Budapest Airport"